# Invoke-SQLCMD in powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

Sorry for trivial question but ...

I have an issue while trying to execute SQL command in PowerShell using invoke command

The issue starts when I tried to add a string into an SQL command:

```
$sqlNAVresutl = Invoke-SQLCMD -Query 'SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DBO name]
WHERE [dbo].[Job Queue Entry].Status = 2 AND [dbo].[$Job Queue Entry].[Object ID to Run] = 52063060 AND [dbo].[$Job Queue Entry].[User ID] = 'Domain\Account'
GO
' 
 -ServerInstance "Server name" -Database "dbo name"
```

The issues starts when I add `Domain\Account` to the code. It works in SQL but not in PowerShell because the whole query is in single quotes (`' '`).

What can I do to read the string inside single quotes?

Comment: Use double single quotes:  ` = ''Domain\Account''`.

Comment: I got error Invoke-SQLCMD : Invalid column name 'Domain\Account'.

Comment: For multi-line SQL you're generally better off using here-strings (`@" .... "@`) so you don't have to worry about escaping (except for `$` if it could start a variable name, as that will still be interpolated -- if you really need a literal `$` in a query you'd use `\`$` to escape that).

Comment: @AjeetVerma Please reserve code formatting (using backticks) for actual *code* and don’t use it for emphasis or around acronyms. Many of your suggested edits are mis-applying this kind of formatting. Ironically for the one use where backticks would have been appropriate, you went for `**` emphasis instead. Have a look at my edit to this question to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

At `-Query` you could use double quotes as at `-ServerInstance` or `-Database`

Comment: I got  error as well .. Invoke-SQLCMD : Invalid object name 'dbo.Queue Entry'.
At line:1 char:17
+ $sqlNAVresutl = Invoke-SQLCMD -Query "SELECT *
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: If your dollar signs are not preceding variable names, escape them with a backtick (`$).

Comment: Ok somehow i figured it out ..... For now it works but strange :)

Answer (score 0):

To **embed `'` (single quotes) in a string literal in PowerShell**, you have 3 options:

---

#### Inside *single-quoted strings* (`'...'`), *double* them:

```
# ' doubled
'Honey, I''m home.'
```

Single-quoted strings are **otherwise interpreted *verbatim***, so no other chars. need escaping.

Conversely, this means that no variable references or expressions are expanded (interpolated) in such strings; if that is needed - e.g., **if `$Job` in your query string is meant to refer to the value of a `$Job` variable defined in PowerShell** - you must u**se a *double*-quoted string (`"..."`)** - see below.

---

#### Inside single-quoted *here-strings* (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`), you don't need to escape `'` at all.

This always multi-line variant of a single-quoted string requires no escaping of any characters.

```
# No escaping needed (ignore the broken syntax highlighting)
@'
Honey, I'm home.
'@
```

**Note**: The closing `'@` must be at the *very start* of the line - not even preceding whitespace allowed.

---

#### Inside *double-quoted strings (`"..."`)*, you don't need to escape `'` at all.

However, since such ***expandable* strings (interpolating strings)** by design interpret `$` as the start of a *variable reference* (e.g., `$var`) or *subexpression* (e.g. `$(1+2)`), you'll then have to **escape *literal* `$` chars. as `` `$ ``**

- `` ` `` (the backtick) generally serves as the escape character in PowerShell (see link below), so you would simililarly use **`` `" `` to escape embedded `"`** chars.
- The need to escape literal `$` chars. as `` `$ `` equally applies to the *here-string* variant of expandable strings
  (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`), but embedded `"` do *not* need escaping.

```
# No escaping of ', but literal $ must be escaped as `$
"Honey, I'm home; I hate my `$Job."
```

---

See also:

- [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules), the official help topic on string literals.

  - [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters), which explains the `` ` ``-prefixed *escape sequences* supported inside *double-quoted* strings, such as `` `t `` to represent a tab character. Note that *Windows PowerShell* supports fewer sequences than PowerShell [Core] 6+.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), which explains *expandable strings* (string interpolation) in detail.